# Ignore certain urls from logging in nginx

Tags: nginx

Im trying to ignore certain urls on my host (as they get requested very often from sync clients and I'm not scared of of any exposure/volunability here)

Typical urls look like;

> /cloud/remote.php/caldav/calendars/xxxx@xxxx.com/personlig/
> /cloud/remote.php/caldav/calendars/xxxx@xxxx.com/contact_birthdays/
> /cloud/remote.php/carddav/xxxx@xxxx.com/
>
> /cloud/remote.php/webdav/xxxx@xxxx.com/

What I'd idealy want to achive is ignore anything after /cloud/remote.php/ or /carddav/ or /caldav/ or /webdav/ a s these belong to sync clients and gets logged seperatedly

I've played around with

```
location = /cloud/remote.php/ {
    access_log off;
}

location = /caldav/calendars/ {
    access_log off;
}
```

But it didnt yield what I expected so I now turn to you guys!

Any suggestions on how I can tackle this?

Answer (score 0):

Use regexps, not equal expression, e.g. for /cloud/remote.php/*:

```
location ~ ^/cloud/remote.php/(caldav|webdav|carddav)(.*)$ {
    access_log off;
}
```

As for regexps priority, manual says:
"The first matching expression stops the search and nginx will use this location. If no regular expression matches a request, then nginx uses the most specific prefix location found earlier."

[How nginx processes a request](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html)

Comment: Please pastebin your full nginx config, server{} part. This location regexp can be overwhelming by other.

Comment: I've uploaded it here, http://pastebin.com/rfYdRpfb . Thanks for looking Aleksey!

Comment: Yes, you have regexp location with more priority:
location ~ ^(/cloud)(/[^/]+\.php)(/.*)?$ {
Move access-log-off location above it and add fastcgi_ commands there too (if you want process this request, just without logging). I also added more info into my answer.